# Async - Which of these is correct

Tags: c#, .net, c#-5.0

From below 2 scenario(s), which one of them is correct way of doing asynchronous programming in c#?

**Scenario-1**

```
public async Task<T1> AddSomethingAsync(param)
{
    return await SomeOtherFunctionFromThirdPartyLibraryForIOAsync(param);
}
```

then

```
List<Task> Tasks=new List<Task>();
foreach(var task in FromAllTasks())
{
    Tasks.Add(AddSomethingAsync(task));
}
await Task.WhenAll(Tasks.AsParallel());
```

**Scenario-2**

```
public async Task<T1> AddSomethingAsync(param)
{
    return SomeOtherFunctionFromThirdPartyLibraryForIOAsync(param);
}
```

then

```
List<Task> Tasks=new List<Task>();
foreach(var task in FromAllTasks())
{
    Tasks.Add(SomeOtherFunctionFromThirdPartyLibraryForIOAsync(task));
}
await Task.WhenAll(Tasks.AsParallel());
```

The only difference between 2 is, later is not having `await` keyword inside `AddSomethingAsync` function.

So here is the update - What I want to know to achieve is, All tasks should be executed in parallel and asynchronously. (My thinking is in scenario-1, the call will be awaited inside AddSomethingAsync and will hurt at upper layer blocking next loop to execute. **confirm**

Comment: `Tasks.AsParallel`? I don't think you know what `AsParallel` does. Just use `await Task.WhenAll(Tasks);`. Even if your functions aren't truly asynchronous, `AsParallel` would be too late to the party.

Comment: @Luaan, can you share more thoughts on "late to the party"?

Comment: You're not parallelizing anything by calling `AsParallel` on an enumerable and enumerating it. PLINQ can only ever help you if the data you're producing is lazy - in your case, all the work has been done already (calling `AddSomethingAsync`).

Answer (score 6):

Scenario 3

```
public Task<T1> AddSomethingAsync(param)
{
    return SomeOtherFunctionFromThirdPartyLibraryForIOAsync(param);
}
```

then

```
List<Task> Tasks=new List<Task>();
foreach(var task in FromAllTasks())
{
    Tasks.Add(SomeOtherFunctionFromThirdPartyLibraryForIOAsync(task));
}
await Task.WhenAll(Tasks);
```

If you are not awaiting anything - you don't need async keyword. Doing AsParallel will do nothing in this case too.

Answer (score -1):

In my opinion it's same. `await` is a mark, means this line execute in the same thread with this method, it'll await in thread.
Actually `async` and `await` is design for method return void. so if this method doesn't return result, it's can be put in a thread alone. Any `async` methods this method called means it'll use same thread with the `void` method, if thoese sub method need result `await`, it's wait inside this thread.
And when you put them in `List<Task>`, it's make no difference.

Comment: currently method returns an object but it is of no use.

Comment: you need understand what situation should use `async & await`. i wrote a blog [here](http://www.cnblogs.com/xianyudotnet/p/5716908.html) about it, you can directly jump to `Async&await&Task` part, it's not in english, but you can check out the experiment result or translate by google.